# Extending adjacency matrix neighbours

Tags: matlab

I have an adjacency matrix. For example, the following,

```
+---+-------------------------------+
|   |   1     2     3     4     5   |
+---+-------------------------------+
| 1 |   0     1     0     0     0   |
| 2 |   1     0     0     0     1   |
| 3 |   0     0     0     1     0   |
| 4 |   0     0     1     0     1   |
| 5 |   0     1     0     1     0   |
+---+-------------------------------+
```

how can we extract the following adjacency matrix, **without for loops**, where for each element (row or column) the neighbors of the already existed neighbors were added? For example, the element `3` has neighbor the element `4` so in the new adjacency matrix the element `3` will have neighbors the elements `4` and `5`.

```
+---+-------------------------------+
|   |   1     2     3     4     5   |
+---+-------------------------------+
| 1 |   0     1     0     0     1   |
| 2 |   1     0     0     1     1   |
| 3 |   0     0     0     1     1   |
| 4 |   0     1     1     0     1   |
| 5 |   1     1     1     1     0   |
+---+-------------------------------+
```

Best regards,

Thoth.

Comment: Would it be always that each row would have not more than one `1` in the input?

Comment: I have made some changes. I hope that clarifies.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If A is your adjacency matrix, then the matrix you want is A2, where:

```
A2 = (A+A^2) > 0
```

This is because the square of an adjacency matrix has components s_ij, where s_ij is the number of paths of length two between i and j. ([In fact (A^n)_ij is the number of paths from i to j of length n](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adjacency_matrix#Properties)).

Therefore, if you add A (which contains all pairs joined by a path of length 1) to A^2 which contains all pairs linked by a path of length two, you'll get the number of paths of length 1 or 2. (And we only care if this is positive for this case). Paths of length two are paths to the neighbours of neighbours.

You might want to set the diagonal back to zero though

Comment: thanks for the tip. I have made some changes in my question. I think your answer need some modifications.

Comment: If `n=2` for path length 2 and `R = A + A^n`. Do you find `R + R' - n*eye(size(A)) > 0` acceptable?

Comment: R' = R, so your answer is roughly 2*R - 2*eye(size(A))>0, this won't quite work. R = A+A^2, and R(logical(eye(size(R)))) = 0 would probably be better.

Comment: This is true (`R'=R`) :). I think this is the answer I wanted. I will mark your post as answered as soon as I convince my self that I do not have any questions :).